# IIS 7 и xdebug (Netbeans)

Tags: php, iis, xdebug, профилирование

Здравствуйте. Необходимо провести профилирование кода. Проект на PHP (Drupal 7) развернут на IIS. Запуск xdebug на LAMP в среде Netbeans у меня не вызывал проблем, но тут возникли трудности. Модуль установлен - проверил в phpinfo(). Настройки php.ini:

```
extension=php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = extras/xdebug_log.log
output_buffering = Off
```

В настройках нетбинса - [порт 9000], [макс. длинна данных 2048], [остановиться в первой строке], [показывать URL запросов], [показать консоль отладки].

Что происходит: запускаю нетбинс от администратора, запускаю "Отладка проекта" в Netbeans, переход в браузер, открытие проекта http://localhost:81/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug , но никакой реакции на точки останова или первую строку, т.е. страница сразу загружается и всё. Кнопки перехода по точкам останова и строкам недоступны. В консоли отладки не показываются переменные. Лог xdebug не пишется. Но если нажать кнопку "Завершить сеанс отладчика", открывается страница http://localhost:81/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=netbeans-xdebug где написано что "DEBUG SESSION ENDED"

Что я не так делаю или в чем может быть еще проблема?

Comment: В логе что-нибудь появляется?

Comment: @Etki, нет. Лог не пишется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После некоторого времени поисков, я все-таки запустил дебаг на нетбинсе. Ответ довольно прост, вместо:

```
extension=php_xdebug.dll
```

нужно подключить так:

```
zend_extension=ext/php_xdebug.dll
```